# Beamer: tikZ-matrix with nodes having multiple lines AND variable width

Tags: beamer, tikz-matrix

I have a slide of the following style: there is a `tikz-matrix` of two columns, the right column requiring TWO properties: 1) it should allow nodes with multiple lines of text/math, 2) the nodes shouldn't all be fixed width.

Earlier, I had got a great solution to the first feature above, which was to use `text width` attribute to describe the nodes. However, now, I find that this would not let me have the flexibility I need in part 2) above. The reason I want 2) is because when the expressions within these right hand side nodes aren't that long, the boxes look a bit ugly if they are still that wide. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark, matrix}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         



\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Our Proof Outline}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=2pt,
            align = left},]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=.5em,
    nodes={anchor=west, 
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->,},
    column 2/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
    text width = 16 em,
    }}](M){
Consider: & some function \\
Want to compare: & {one function and\\  a much longer function}\\
Our interpolating function: & a really really long mathematical expression here\\ 
Observe: & {observation 1 \\ observation 2 }\\ 
};          

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still LaTeX, so you can use a `tabular` to have two rows of variable width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark, matrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         



\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Our Proof Outline}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=2pt,
            align = left},]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=.5em,
    nodes={anchor=west, 
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->,},
    column 2/.style={nodes={optimization problem}}](M){
Consider: & some function\\
Want to compare: & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
one function and\\
a much longer function\end{tabular}\\
Our interpolating function: & 
{$\begin{lgathered}
E=mc^2\\ \quad=f=g=h=k
\end{lgathered}$}\\ 
Observe: & \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
observation 1\\ 
observation 2%
\end{tabular}\\ 
};          

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note:

- One needs to be a bit careful with the spaces at the end of the cells before `\\`.
- You can use environments with `&` in if you use an ampersand replacement, but this is not needed here. (This has been used in the later answer by Zarko.)

Here is an example with an `aligned` environment and symmetric spacing. (The spacing at the left and right is set by `inner xsep=2pt,` of `optimization problem`, which I increased here to `4pt`.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,overlay-beamer-styles,tikzmark, matrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\section{Proofs}         



\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Our Proof Outline}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = green,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=4pt,
            align = left},
            ]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=.5em,
    nodes={anchor=west, 
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->,},
    column 2/.style={nodes={optimization problem}},
    ampersand replacement=\&](M){
Consider: \& some function\\
Want to compare: \& \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
one function and\\
a much longer function\end{tabular}\\
Our interpolating function: \& 
{$\begin{aligned}
E&=mc^2\\ &=f=g=h=k
\end{aligned}$}\\ 
Observe: \& \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
observation 1\\ 
observation 2%
\end{tabular}\\ 
};          

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! So, in the above example, the "really, really long mathematical expression here" needs to be replaced by an actually long mathematical expression (so I anticipate using ```\multline```. How would that work in this code?

Comment: @lazulikid I added a `multline*` environment. Except for the fact that it starts a new line that one needs to undo in one way or another there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar idea as at @Schrödinger's cat answer: where is needed multi line text in matrix's cells, is used `\makecell` command (which essential contain tabular environment) from the `makecell` package and math environments defined in `amsmath` packages (loaded by `beamer`.

For proper work of ampersands in `aligned` math, for matrix is used `ampersand replacement=\&` for separating of matrix cells:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, overlay-beamer-styles }
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \section{Proofs}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Our Proof Outline}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [ampersand replacement=\&,
             matrix of nodes,
             column sep=.5em, row sep=1em,
             nodes={anchor=west,
                    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->},
             column 2/.style={nodes={rounded corners,
                                     draw = green,
                                     inner ysep=5pt, inner xsep=2pt, 
                                     minimum width=4 em}}
            ]
{
Consider:   \& some function \\
Want to compare: 
            \& \makecell[l]{one function and\\ a much longer function}   \\
Our interpolating function: 
            \& $\begin{aligned}
                c^2 & = a^2 + b^2 \\ 
                a   & = \sqrt{c^2-b^2}
                \end{aligned}$   \\
Observe:    \& \makecell[l]{observation 1\\ observation 2}   \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which final result is:

[image]